# What to pass as parameter in change of model-bound select if anything?

Tags: angular

If I have a model-bound select and want to handle the change event, do I need to pass anything in my event handler - or should I be able to access the model-bound value eg. program?

```html
    <select [(ngModel)]="changeDetails.program" name="program" #program="ngModel" required 
         class="form-control" (change)="HandleChange(???)">
             <option *ngFor="let subProgram of programs" [value]="subProgram.value"> 
             {{subProgram}}</option>
    </select>
```

in the component class:

```js
    HandleChange(???) {
       // use model value on class? or parameter?
    }
```

Comment: Maybe using `$event` where you have `???` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `ngModelChange` event, and pass `$event` to the event handler. That parameter will have the new selected value:

```
(ngModelChange)="HandleChange($event)"
```

If, for some reason, you prefer to handle the `change` DOM event, you can pass the selected value with `$event.target.value` (since `$event` refers to the DOM event object in that case):

```
(change)="HandleChange($event.target.value)"
```

In both cases, the event handler would get the new value:

```
HandleChange(value) {
 console.log("New selected value", value);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-42ruog?file=src/app/app.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, as your example clearly works.  However, for some reason my $event value is undefined when the handler is called. The only difference Is I left off the the fact that this select is within a form tag

Comment: @bitshift - Can you make a stacklitz showing your case?

Comment: Good grief, I found it... it was a freaking case issue... needed to be "id" instead of "Id".  Just spent 2 hours staring at what was right in front of my face.  Just had to see the model data in the dev console.  All working now.  Thanks!